# Find the possible integers $a,b,c$ such that their sum is 100

Tags: abstract-algebra

The excercise asks to use an action of the symmetric group to find the number of possible ternes $(a,b,c)$, with $a,b,c > 0$ such that $a+b+c = 100$ and $a \le b \le c ?$".

Comment: First consider the question without the condition $x\leq y\leq z.$ Then realize that six of those solutions correspond to one solution when $x,y,z$ are distinct. When two of the values are equal, there are three unordered triples. There are no triples all equal.

Comment: So, the number of solutions to your question is equal to the number of orbits of the unsorted question when acted on by $S_3.$

Answer (score 0):

Denote the equation x+y+z=100 by E.Remark that if $(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})$ is a solution of $E$ and $\alpha$ is an element of $S_{3}$,then $(x_{\alpha(1)},x_{\alpha(2)},x_{\alpha(3)})$ is still a solution,So $S_{3}$ acts on the set of Solutions of E,and each orbit contains exactly one  triplet $(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})$ satisfying the required inequalities,but there are orbits of length six,and other orbits of length three(there no orbits of length one since 3 doesn't divide 100),So we need to consider the number of Solutions of the equation 2x+y=100 (which is $3\times 49$ solutions) and the number of Solutions of E (which is 4851).the number of orbits of length three is 49,wheras the number of orbits of length six is (4851-3*49)/6=784,hence the number of required solutions is 833.

Comment: This is a beautiful solution! Thank you very much! However i don't understand why the number of solutions of E is 4851

Comment: E is equivalent to the following equation x+y=100-z,So once we determine (x,y),z is uniquely determined.the equation can be reduced to finding couples (x,y) such that $x+y \leq 99$,geometrically we are counting points of the "positive  quadrant of the integer lattice" points belowthe line $y=99-x$,so for $x=1$, we have 98 possible values for y,continuing this way, u find a sum of terms of an arithemetic sequence.